# Unable to cause horizontalSlider to slide at regular time intervals

Tags: qt

I need to make a Music Player using Qt, in which the slider slides as the song progresses.

```
this->ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(10);
sleep(1);
this->ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(20);
```

I was trying things like above but could not cause it to display the changing values, as the program pauses for 1 second and only the second value(20) is displayed.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Nothing will happen unless you allow the event loop to proceed.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: The slider should slide, like a progress bar after every second (by value length of song in seconds / 100). So i was trying something like, show value, sleep for 1 second, show next value, sleep and so on.

Comment: Take a look at [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) and connect the `QTimer::timeout` signal to a function that updates the slider.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it now

Comment: What are you using for the actual playback?
Maybe it could emit a signal that indicates progress, you could the update the slider in a slot connected to that

Comment: @KevinKrammer I am using pygame.mixer in pyQt. It worked by using the get_position of song function in it. I multi-threaded the play and change slider value functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever library you use for audio playback should asynchronously notify you of progress in playing the file. You should react to such progress and update the slider. Using hardcoded delays will quickly desynchronize the slider from real audio playback, even if we forget the fact that you block the event loop.

In any modern application development framework there's generally no need ever to block a thread to sleep. If you write such code, it's the wrong approach in 99.99% of the cases.

Comment: True, you will have a lag of up to 1s for all user interactions (and non-input events) while playing. This would cause a very bad user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Sleeping will block the program for 1 second. Meaning that anything going on (music playback, or any process running inside your app) will basically not work.

What will happen is that the program will set the value to 10, sleep one second (nothing will happen), set 20, and block the program for 1 second again. So basically, your program blocks all the time, and sets the slider's value every second.

The solution is to get the progress value, for example :

```
int total_time, current_time; //Durations in seconds
int progress; //Will hold the progress percentage

//Somehow you get the total song time and the current song timer
//...
progress = (current_time/total_time)*100
this->ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(progress);
```

Or :

```
/*When initializing the slider*/
int total_time; //Duration in seconds
//Somehow you get the the total song time...
//...
this->ui->horizontalSlider->setRange(0,total_time);
```

And in your routine

```
/* In the routine where you refresh the slider */
int current_time; //Duration in seconds

//Somehow you get the the current song timer...
//...
this->ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(current_time);
```